# Feed script variable to command that prompts for user input

Tags: shell-script, variable

I have a shellscript `ABCD.sh` and it will have a command to upload a file onto server which will prompt for username and password.

Instead of providing username and password there, I would like to pass the username and password as an external argument only, how it is possible?

```
username =$1
password=$2
pushcommand
```

The `pushcommand` will ask to enter username and password; the shellscript should automatically take it from `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

If pushcommand simply reads first username and then password from standard input, separated by newline, you can do the following:

```
echo "$username\n$password" | pushcommand
```

The "echo" call here will output the username and password variables on separate lines.
The "|" means "take the output of the command on the left, and feed it as input to the command on the right". This construct is called a "pipe" in shell scripts.

For scripting more complex interactions, I'd recommend looking at [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) or possibly [kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/skermit.html#scripts).
To get help with expect or kermit, you'd have to post an example on how an interactive use of pushcommand actually looks like, e.g. what prompts it displays and so on.

Comment: Thank you rose I tried and it again asking me a username and password my command is " echo "$username\n$password" | git push  https://github.com//store.git master

Comment: For using git in a shell script, I'd recommend avoiding username/password authentication and using SSH instead of HTTP for pushing.  

Sections 4.1 ("Git on the Server - The Protocols"), 4.3 ("Generating Your SSH Public Key") and 6 ("Github") of the Git Book ( https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 ) might be helpful in that regard.

If you really want to use HTTP and username+password for pushing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646476/5199419 looks promising.

Comment: Hi ..I tried ssh authentication but it did not work so I am trying to pass username and password

Comment: any other way to pass the username and password?

Comment: Have tried the response by bk2204 in the link from my last comment?

Comment: yes But I am getting error "f(){ printf 'username=%s\npassword=%s\n'   };f store: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Everything up-to-date
"

Comment: f(){ printf 'username=%s\npassword=%s\n' vishnu@gmail.com 123 };f store: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file